# Selecting rows conflicting values in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, select

I am having trouble selecting rows in MySQL. I do not want some rows to be selected, but they are being selected.

My query:

```
SELECT  name,url
    FROM  additions
    WHERE  enabled = 1
      AND  picture = 1
      AND  name LIKE '%value%'
      OR  tags LIKE '%value%'
      OR  subtext LIKE '%value%';
```

I do not want the rows that do not have a picture (`picture = 0`) and also rows that are not enabled (`enabled = 0`) to be selected. I think the rows match because either the name, tags and/or subtext matches the `value`, because of the `OR` condition in WHERE clause.

I want only the rows to be selected that have a picture and are enabled, regardless of the match in name, tags, subtext. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

**The answer:** as ypercube said, the solution is:

`adding parentheses around the OR conditions`

like so:

```sql
SELECT name,url FROM additions WHERE enabled = 1 AND picture = 1 AND (name LIKE '%value%' OR tags LIKE '%value%' OR subtext LIKE '%value%');
```

With the parentheses, AND will take precedence and the entire section in the `LIKE` value comparison will have to be true together with the other evaluations, like `enabled = 1` and `picture = 1`. Without the parentheses the OR statements are evaluated individually (and if one of them happens to be true, a row will be selected).